# VS 2005 C++ edit content of the CRichEditCtrl instance

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2005, richedit

I've installed a Windows XP Professional SP3 on a VMWare image and the Visual Studio 2005 on it. I've created a new dialog based C++ MFC project with /clr support. I've put a RichEdit 2.0 control onto the auto-generated dialog and I'm trying to read up a text file and put its content into this RichEdit 2.0 control by button click without formatting. I've added a variable to the RichEdit 2.0 called pCRichEditCtrl and here is my code which doesn't work.

CWinApp inheritance:

```
BOOL CTextFormatterApp::InitInstance()
{
    ...
    AfxInitRichEdit2();
    CWinApp::InitInstance();
    ...
}
```

CDialog inheritance:

```
void CTextFormatterDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{   
    StreamReader^ objReader = gcnew StreamReader("c:\\text.txt");
    String ^sLine = "";
    sLine = objReader->ReadLine();
    while (sLine != nullptr)
    {
            pCRichEditCtrl.SetSel(pCRichEditCtrl.GetTextLength(), -1);
            pCRichEditCtrl.ReplaceSel(CString(sLine));
            sLine = objReader->ReadLine();
    }

    objReader->Close();
}
```

I don't know whether it counts but I get the following warnings at linking:

> TextFormatterDlg.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000016) for 'AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO'; image may not run
>
> TextFormatter.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000012) for 'AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO'; image may not run
>
> TextFormatterDlg.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000015) for 'IAccessibleProxy'; image may not run

I'm not sure what I'm doing because I'm familiar only with newer frameworks and I don't know either Windows.

Input file exists, I can see the read text if I debug the application but I can't see any changes in the edit box. I've tried to call **pCRichEditCtrl.UpdateData(true);** but nothing has changed.

Is it enough to add a variable for getting the controller of the box (pCRichEditCtrl)? It seems to the pointer doesn't point to the proper control item.

Do you have any idea what is missing?

Comment: I have given an answer to load your control using straight MFC -- how/where do you declare `pCRichEditCtrl`? and how do you connect it to your control?

Comment: I added it via GUI: right click on the RichEdit control -> Add variable...

Additional info: if I add the following line then RichEdit shows the text, but only from the 2nd line: **UpdateData(TRUE);** It's weird.

Comment: edited my answer with settings for `pCRichEditCtrl`, a simple test project as below works for me without `UpdateData()`, this is necessary only if you have variables of type "value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I share the final solution with the community to be available for those who faces with the same issue. I don't know why do I have to use `Update(FALSE);` on the `CWinApp` inheritance two times but it solves everything. If someone has an idea or a better (nicer) solution don't hesitate to share it with us, I'll move the accepted flag to that version (if it is possible, I haven't tried it before).

```
void CTextFormatterDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    StreamReader^ objReader = gcnew StreamReader("c:\\text.txt");
    String ^sLine = objReader->ReadLine();
    UpdateData(FALSE); //this is the first unexpected first aid
    while (sLine != nullptr)
    {
        pCRichEditCtrl.SetSel(pCRichEditCtrl.GetTextLength(), -1);
        pCRichEditCtrl.ReplaceSel(CString(sLine + "\r\n"));
        UpdateData(FALSE); //this is the second unexpected first aid
        sLine = objReader->ReadLine();
    }

    objReader->Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use CLI to just read text files, try something like:

```
void CTextFormatterDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{   CStdioFile f1;
    CString sLine;
    if (!f1.Open(_T("c:\\text.txt"), CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeText))
        return;
    while (f1.ReadString(sLine))
    {   pCRichEditCtrl.SetSel(pCRichEditCtrl.GetTextLength(), -1);
        pCRichEditCtrl.ReplaceSel(sLine);
    }

    f1.Close();
}
```

**EDIT**: control variable `pCRichEditCtrl`

a) should be declared in the dialog class as `CRichEditCtrl pCRichEditCtrl;`

b) should be connected to the ID of the control (e.g.: `IDC_RICHEDIT21`), like

```
void CTextFormatterDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{   CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_RICHEDIT21, pCRichEditCtrl);
}
```

c) I have tested the following code and it works for me (adds "aa" to the control window on each button click)

```
pCRichEditCtrl.SetSel(pCRichEditCtrl.GetTextLength(), -1);
pCRichEditCtrl.ReplaceSel(TEXT("aa"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint but it doesn't solve my main problem. File reading works for me.

Comment: Thank you for your additional work on my problem.
a) added automatically by GUI action (add variable...)
b) same as a)
c) doesn't work for me
I have to use `UpdateData(FALSE);` before the `while` cycle AND in the cycle also. I don't know why but this is the only way to make it work.
Maybe the problem is that I don't know anything about the workflow of this version of the Visual Studio framework. Could you offer me a good on-line guide about the basics of this specific version, especially about the control and event handling? It would be enough for me to give you the point ;)

Comment: Control and event handling has not changed much over the VS versions, this is the clearest article I cound find: http://www.functionx.com/visualc/controls/managing.htm (most of the other articles describe how to manage variables of type "value", in your case it is a variable of type "control")